# Opening ssh access to virtual machine using iptables

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, iptables

I wrote the follwing iptables rules. but there is one problem. I can't ssh to my vmware machine. how can I handle it?

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=`hostname -I| awk '{print $1}'`
LOOP=127.0.0.1
if=eth0

# Clear any previous rules.
iptables -F

# Default drop policy.
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Prevent external packets from using loopback addr
iptables -A INPUT -i $if -s $LOOP -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i $if -s $LOOP -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i $if -d $LOOP -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i $if -d $LOOP -j DROP

# Drop any tcp packet that does not start a connection with a syn flag.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP -m comment --comment "Dropping any tcp packet that doesn't start a connection with a syn flag!"

# Drop any invalid packet that could not be identified.
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Drop invalid packets.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP

#Allow working on localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -s $LOOP -d $LOOP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -s $LOOP -d $LOOP -j ACCEPT

#Allow ping from inside to outside
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

#Openning outgoing trafic
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $if -s $ip -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $if -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


iptables -A INPUT -i $if -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT #The ip of my local virtual machine
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $if -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP
```

Also result of:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1           
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW /* Dropping any tcp packet that doesn't start a connection with a syn flag! */
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x03/0x03
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x06
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x05/0x05
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x11/0x01
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x30/0x20
   14  3687 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0
  808  280K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       x.x.x.x      0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1           

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 7 packets, 420 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   14  3687 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
 1087  167K ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth0    y.y.y.y           0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

## update

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x03/0x03
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x06
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x05/0x05
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x11/0x01
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x30/0x20
    9  3427 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0
  751  418K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       x.x.x.x      0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1           

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 7 packets, 420 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    9  3427 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
  795  152K ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth0    y.y.y.y           0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score -1):

Open incoming connections to port 22

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

The ESTABLISHED,RELATED rule (which you already have) should sort out the rest.

Comment: Also remove iptables -A OUTPUT -o $if -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP

Answer (score -1):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Did you restart the service?

Comment: Yes. I off it and again on it